# Update SQL from React

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, web, frontend

I build a react app using nodejs and mysql. I want to update an entry from react but the following code doesn't working and I can't understan what is the problem. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

// from index.js

```
script.get('/updatepost/:id', (req, res) => {
    let sql = `UPDATE posts SET name = '${req.body.name}', school='${req.body.school}' WHERE id = ${req.params.id}`;
    let query = connection.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
        res.send('Post updated...');
    })
});
```

//from react component

```
axios(`http://localhost:4000/updatepost/${userId}`, {
method: 'PATCH',
data: qs.stringify(data);
})
```

Comment: Looks like your server is only accepting `GET` requests at that endpoint, yet your frontend code is using `PATCH`

Comment: I know, but i don't know how to fix that.

Comment: I'm no expert with Express, but having just checked the API documentation it seems you can just use `script.patch` instead of `script.get`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the brackets (). The query should be as below

let sql = `UPDATE posts SET name = '${newName}', school='${newSchool}' WHERE id = ${req.params.id}`;